# SCNetworkReachabilityFlags bitwise AND comparison error with Xcode 7

Tags: swift2, xcode7

Having just updated to Xcode 7, I'm getting an error on previous code and I can't understand why.

This is an example of code I have:

```
private func isReachable(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
  return flags & SCNetworkReachabilityFlags.Reachable != 0
}
```

Yielding the error: Binary operator '&' cannot be applied to two 'SCNetworkReachabilityFlags' operands

I'm assuming this is an update to Swift, but I can't find anything about it. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Swift 2, you have to use `.contains`

```
private func isReachable(flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) -> Bool {
  return flags.contains(.Reachable)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, much appreciated.